# Emacs -- dired-mode test to determine remote server name / address

Tags: emacs, elisp, dired, tramp

Is there a test to obtain the remote server name (e.g., `localhost`) or address  (e.g., `12.34.56.789`) in the `current-buffer` with `dired-mode` active?

I suppose I could use `string-match` or `split-string` and then `equal`, but I thought there might be a handy function like get server name.

**iphone -- dired-directory**

```
/ssh:root@localhost#2222:/var/mobile/Applications/F30B1574-5979-4764-8742-7F9DB2863094/Documents/.0.data:
```

**shared server -- dired-directory**

```
/ssh:lawlist@12.34.56.789:/home/lawlist/public_html:
```

Comment: This seems to be more of a TRAMP issue than specific to DIRED.

Comment: @Barmar -- thank you for helping me reach the right target audience. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's tramp paths you're interested in, then you probably want to look at `tramp-dissect-file-name` or `with-parsed-tramp-file-name`. e.g.:

```el
(tramp-file-name-host (tramp-dissect-file-name path))
```

If you want to exclude the port, use `tramp-file-name-real-host`.

You might need to check `file-remote-p` first, if that's not already certain; and that also leads us to a nice shortcut I'd never noticed before:

```el
(file-remote-p path 'host)
```

(no port-less option here, if would seem)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help -- greatly appreciated!  :)  For *localhost* with port 2222, I ended up using the condition of `(and (file-remote-p dired-directory 'localhost) (equal (tramp-file-name-real-host (tramp-dissect-file-name dired-directory)) "localhost"))`.  For the other remote server, I'm using virtually the same thing -- just substituting *localhost* and replacing it with *12.34.56.789*.