# How to check if connected to remote server?

Tags: emacs, elisp, tramp

I use tramp to connect to my company's servers.
I would like to customize my functions to work differently if I am accessing local files vs remote ones.

Is there a variable I could check if the buffer I am accessing is on a remote server or my local machine?

Something like:

```
if(TRAMP_CONNECTED)
 Do this
else
 Do that
```

Comment: I asked a similar question that phils previously answered -- his answer, plus my comment underneath, may address your issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24481891/2112489  In my case, I also wanted to distinguish which remote I was connected to -- since I have a few.

Comment: lawlist, for some reason this code: (and (file-remote-p dired-directory 'localhost) (equal (tramp-file-name-real-host (tramp-dissect-file-name dired-directory)) "remote-name"))  return error if executed while inside a file. Is there a way to change it so it checks whether buffer is file or directory?

Comment: Perhaps using `file-directory-p` -- the doc-string is as follows:  *`(file-directory-p FILENAME)` -- Return `t` if FILENAME names an existing directory.  Symbolic links to directories count as directories.  See `file-symlink-p` to distinguish symlinks.*  Depending on  the usage, you might also be interested in `buffer-file-name` as a variable or `(buffer-file-name)` as a function -- both are usually set when there is a file; however, some modes set a non-file-visiting buffer equal to a specific `buffer-file-name`.

Comment: I need to correct a slight misstatement in my previous comment -- the *value* for `buffer-file-name` is sometimes set by some modes for non-file-visiting buffers.  The doc-string for the function `buffer-file-name` states:  *Return name of file BUFFER is visiting, or nil if none -- No argument or nil as argument means use the current buffer.*  I have not yet seen an example where the *value* would be different between the variable or the function that returns the *value*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most robust check is likely `default-directory`. This variable is always set buffer local. If `(file-remote-p default-directory)` returns non-nil, your buffer is under Tramp control.